# Python & Pandas: How to query if a list-type column contains something?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, which contains info about movies. It has a column called `genre`, which contains a list of genres it belongs to. For example:

```
df['genre']

## returns 

0       ['comedy', 'sci-fi']
1       ['action', 'romance', 'comedy']
2       ['documentary']
3       ['crime','horror']
...
```

I want to know how can I query the dataframe, so it returns the movie belongs to a cerain genre?

For example, something may like `df['genre'].contains('comedy')` returns 0 or 1.

I know for a list, I can do things like:

```
'comedy' in  ['comedy', 'sci-fi']
```

However, in pandas, I didn't find something similar, the only thing I know is `df['genre'].str.contains()`, but it didn't work for the list type.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) for create `mask` and then [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = df.genre.apply(lambda x: 'comedy' in x)
df1 = df[mask]
print (df1)
                       genre
0           [comedy, sci-fi]
1  [action, romance, comedy]
```

Comment: want to search more than 2 values in a column

Comment: You can modify it as: ('value1' in x) and ('value2' in x)

Comment: How to handle if the list is blank in some rows, like []

Comment: @Hardikgupta - If missing value like `df = pd.DataFrame([[['comedy', 'bar']],
                    [['bar', 'baz']],[np.nan]], columns=['genre'])` then use `mask = df.genre.apply(lambda x: 'comedy' in x if x == x else False)`

Comment: @jezrael, can you search with a list? With say filter_list = ['comedy', 'horror', 'documentary']? I tried mask = df.genre.apply(lambda x: [filter_list] in x) but get an empty df

Comment: @queste - you can try `df.genre.map(set(filter_list).issubset)`

Comment: @jezrael - could you write out the whole command for searching with a list through a dataframe with a column of lists that might also contain NaN, i.e., ```mask = ```, please? I can't get my head round your idea. Do you mean ```mask = df.genre.map(set(filter_list).issubset)```? If so, that doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 40):

using sets

```
df.genre.map(set(['comedy']).issubset)

0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

---

```
df.genre[df.genre.map(set(['comedy']).issubset)]

0             [comedy, sci-fi]
1    [action, romance, comedy]
dtype: object
```

---

***presented in a way I like better***

```
comedy = set(['comedy'])
iscomedy = comedy.issubset
df[df.genre.map(iscomedy)]
```

***more efficient***

```
comedy = set(['comedy'])
iscomedy = comedy.issubset
df[[iscomedy(l) for l in df.genre.values.tolist()]]
```

***using `str` in two passes***
slow! and not perfectly accurate!

```
df[df.genre.str.join(' ').str.contains('comedy')]
```

Comment: _more efficient_ Do you have any benchmarks/measurements for that? I'm curious, I wouldn't expect `.map()` to be that much shorter.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/cebc70cc277462176edea73bb71eaad9f83e9f47/pandas/core/strings.py#L207), you can use `.str.contains(..., regex=False)`.

Comment: That was my initial thought which unfortunately doesn't work as it returns `True` even for partial string matches.

Comment: It correctly excludes partial string matches for me. e.g. `genre = pd.Series([['comedy', 'sci-fi'], ['action', 'romance', 'comedy'], ['documentary'], ['crime', 'horror']]); genre.str.contains('omed', regex=False)` correctly gives all False.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `regex=False` and `.str.contains` will work for list values as you would expect:

```
In : df['genre'].str.contains('comedy', regex=False)
Out:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: genre, dtype: bool
```

Comment: It does not work with tuples instead of lists in my experience, do you know why?

Answer (score 2):

A complete example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame([[['foo', 'bar']],
                    [['bar', 'baz']]], columns=['list_column'])
print(data)
  list_column
0  [foo, bar]
1  [bar, baz]

filtered_data = data.loc[
    lambda df: df.list_column.apply(
        lambda l: 'foo' in l
    )
]
print(filtered_data)
  list_column
0  [foo, bar]
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in all three ways as suggested, using `str.contains`, `set` or `apply` and `in`. Although using `set` is the most efficient way to achieve this.

Here's a performance comparison of the three methods on an extrapolated dataframe with 10,000 rows:

#### set

```
%%timeit -n 500 -r 35
df[df.genre.map(set(['comedy']).issubset)]
2.23 ms ± 154 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 35 runs, 500 loops each)
```

#### apply & in

```
%%timeit -n 500 -r 35
df[df.genre.apply(lambda x: 'comedy' in x)]
2.36 ms ± 359 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 35 runs, 500 loops each)
```

#### str.contains

```
%%timeit -n 500 -r 35
df[df['genre'].str.contains('comedy', regex=False)]
2.83 ms ± 299 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 35 runs, 500 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the `isin` method to return a new dataframe that contains **boolean** values where each item is located.

```
df1[df1.name.isin(['Rohit','Rahul'])]
```

here `df1` is a `dataframe` object and `name` is a string series

```
>>> df1[df1.name.isin(['Rohit','Rahul'])]
   sample1   name  Marks  Class 
0        1  Rohit     34     10
1        2  Rahul     56     12
>>> type (df1)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame> 
>>> df1.head()
   sample1    name  Marks  Class
0        1   Rohit     34     10
1        2   Rahul     56     12
2        3   ankit     78     11
3        4   sajan     98     10
4        5  chintu     76      9
```