# Python Pandas Series.isin doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a Series

```
8                    [11820]
9                    [11820]
10                   [11820]
11                   [11820]
12                   [11820]
27                   [10599]
28                   [10599]
29                   [10599]
31              [661, 10599]
32              [661, 10599]
33                    [7322]
34                     [0]
37                     [661]
39                     [661]
40                     [661]
49      [0, 661, 662, 663]
```

I want to filter this Series with something like `points[points.isin([0])]` to get

```
34                     [0]
49      [0, 661, 662, 663]
```

but as a result I get 0 Features.

Comment: You are searching for lists. .isin() looks for values

Comment: @lhay86 yes, I want to find all features, which lists contain my value. Not only strict accordance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python & Pandas: How to query if a list-type column contains something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41518920/python-pandas-how-to-query-if-a-list-type-column-contains-something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple way to check, if your value (0) is in the list, is by using `apply` on your series:**

```
s = s[s.apply(lambda x: 0 in x)]
```

**Some explanation:**
For every row it checks, whether 0 is in the list.

Apply returns a "True/False" series, where for every row True means that 0 is in the list inside the row.

After that your first series (s) is being filtered by this "True/False" series via [].

**Sample code:**

```
# This is your series
s = pd.Series([[0],
               [11820],
               [11820], 
               [10599],
               [0, 661, 662, 663]])

# This is the solution
s = s[s.apply(lambda x: 0 in x)]

# Print the result
print(s)

0                   [0]
4    [0, 661, 662, 663]
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

`pd.Series.isin` works by hashing and works on the entire element, i.e. it won't consider a partial match. Even for an exact match, since a list cannot be hashed, `pd.Series.isin` won't work with a series of lists.

#### Partial match

You can use a custom function with `pd.Series.apply`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[1, 2], [0], [0, 2, 3]]})

search_list = [0]  # list of scalars

mask = df['A'].apply(lambda x: any(i in x for i in search_list))
res = df[mask]

print(res)

           A
1        [0]
2  [0, 2, 3]
```

#### Exact match

You can convert your series to tuples, which are hashable, before any comparison. Then compare your series of tuples with a list of tuples.

```
search_list = [[0]]  # list of lists

mask = df['A'].map(tuple).isin(list(map(tuple, search_list)))
res = df[mask]

print(res)

     A
1  [0]
```

Note operations with `object` dtype series will necessarily be inefficient. If possible, you should split your series of lists into multiple series of integers. Although, in this case, this may be cumbersome given the inconsistent list lengths.