# I have mixed level JSON to parse in python, Having trouble with Keys

Tags: python, json

I have a set of nested JSON and it I am doing the following thus far:

```
r = session.get(search_url, auth=HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication=OPTIONAL), verify=False)
json_data = json.loads(r.content)
flattened_data = json_normalize(json_data['documents'])
print(list(flattened_data))
```

This outputs the following results:

```
['affected_users', 'aggregatedLabels', 'aliases', 'assignedFolder', 'assigneeIdentity', 'attachments', 'authorizations', 'autoUpgrade.workingHours', 'conversation', 'createDate', 'dedupes', 'deleted', 'description', 'descriptionContentType', 'editCount', 'engagementList', 'extensions.backlog.priority', 'extensions.effort.effortEstimatedLocal.effort', 'extensions.effort.effortEstimatedLocal.unit', 'extensions.effort.effortEstimatedRecursiveSum.effort', 'extensions.effort.effortEstimatedRecursiveSum.unit', 'extensions.effort.effortRemainingLocalSum.effort', 'extensions.effort.effortRemainingLocalSum.unit', 'extensions.effort.effortRemainingRecursiveSum.effort', 'extensions.effort.effortRemainingRecursiveSum.unit', 'extensions.effort.effortSpentLocalSum.effort', 'extensions.effort.effortSpentLocalSum.unit', 'extensions.effort.effortSpentRecursiveSum.effort', 'extensions.effort.effortSpentRecursiveSum.unit', 'extensions.tt.assignedGroup', 'extensions.tt.building', 'extensions.tt.caseType', 'extensions.tt.category', 'extensions.tt.city', 'extensions.tt.endCode', 'extensions.tt.ecd', 'extensions.tt.impact', 'extensions.tt.item', 'extensions.tt.justification', 'extensions.tt.migrationStatus', 'extensions.tt.minImpact', 'extensions.tt.resolution', 'extensions.tt.rootCause', 'extensions.tt.rootCauseDetails', 'extensions.tt.status', 'extensions.tt.type', 'frames', 'id', 'identityTimestamped', 'inheritedLabels', 'isTicket', 'labels', 'lastAssignedDate', 'lastResolvedByIdentity', 'lastResolvedDate', 'lastUpdatedActualDate', 'lastUpdatedConversationDate', 'lastUpdatedDate', 'lastUpdatedIdentity', 'next_step.action', 'next_step.exceptions', 'next_step.owner', 'parentTasks', 'requesterIdentity', 'rootCauses', 'rulesReceipt', 'schedule.estimatedCompletionDate', 'schedule.estimatedStartDate', 'schedule.needByDate', 'schema', 'slaReceipts', 'status', 'stickyThreadId', 'submitterIdentity', 'subtasks', 'tags', 'threads', 'title', 'watchers']
```

From this list I am trying to get only certain keys and their values into the data frame:

```
    print(flattened_data['assigneeIdentity',
#                         'createDate',
#                         'description',
#                         'extensions.tt.assignedGroup',
#                         'extensions.tt.category',
#                         'extensions.tt.endCode',
#                         'extensions.tt.ecd',
#                         'extensions.tt.impact',
#                         'extensions.tt.item',
#                         'extensions.tt.justification',
#                         'extensions.tt.resolution',
#                         'extensions.tt.rootCause',
#                         'extensions.tt.rootCauseDetails',
#                         'extensions.tt.status',
#                         'extensions.tt.type',
#                         'id',
#                         'labels',
#                         'lastAssignedDate',
#                         'lastResolvedByIdentity',
#                         'lastResolvedDate',
#                         'lastUpdatedActualDate',
#                         'lastUpdatedConversationDate',
#                         'lastUpdatedDate',
#                         'lastUpdatedIdentity',
#                         'requesterIdentity',
#                         'submitterIdentity',
#                         'title',
#                         'watchers'])
```

When I do this I get a key error. so the base JSON that comes in is as follows for the fields I list above and an idea of the nesting level of each one; each 'item' is an integer under the documents element with then more nested elements I need:

```
documents:
          0:
             extensions:
                         tt:
                             category:
                             type:
                             item:
                             assignedGroup:
                             impact:
                             justification:
                             endCode:
                             rootCause:
                             rootCauseDetails:
                             status:
              id:
              title:
              lastAssignedDate:
              createDate:
              lastUpdatedActualDate:
              lastResolvedDate:
              lastResolvedByIdentity:
              lastUpdatedIdentity:
              assigneeIdentity:
              submitterIdentity:
              requesterIdentity:
              identityTimestamped:
              lastUpdatedConversationDate:
              lastUpdatedDate:
          1:
             extensions:
                         tt:
                             category:
                             type:
                             item:
                             assignedGroup:
                             impact:
                             justification:
                             endCode:
                             rootCause:
                             rootCauseDetails:
                             status:
              id:
              title:
              lastAssignedDate:
              createDate:
              lastUpdatedActualDate:
              lastResolvedDate:
              lastResolvedByIdentity:
              lastUpdatedIdentity:
              assigneeIdentity:
              submitterIdentity:
              requesterIdentity:
              identityTimestamped:
              lastUpdatedConversationDate:
              lastUpdatedDate:
```

How do I get this and the values into a dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flattened_data` should already be a valid DataFrame. The error appears to be that you're trying to print `flattened_data["key1", "key2", ...]` which would look for the column *named* `["key1", "key2", ...]` in `flattened_data`. In essence, you are telling the DataFrame *"Get the column whose name **is** this list"*.

To get a list of columns from a DataFrame, you should try `flattened_data[["key1", "key2", ...]]`, which is instead saying *"Get all of the columns whose name **is in** this list"*.

What could also be happening here is that you have a DataFrame with columns `["0.id", "0.title", ..., "1.id", "1.title", ...]`, with just one row: the values assigned to each of those paths in the JSON object.

However, `pandas.io.json.normalize_json()` can take a list of dictionaries as an argument, so instead of using `flattened_data = json_normalize(json_data['documents'])`, using a list of the sub-dictionaries in `json_data['documents']` (for example, `json_data['documents'].values()`) should return the correct DataFrame.

```py
records = list(json_data['documents'].values())
flattened_data = json_normalize(records)
```

Then, you could retrieve the columns you want with:

```py
 print(flattened_data[['assigneeIdentity', 'createDate', 'description', 'extensions.tt.assignedGroup', ...]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Citing something from a [fantastic response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41518920/python-pandas-how-to-query-if-a-list-type-column-contains-something) that I just commented on today. Maybe this will help:

```
import pandas as pd

r = session.get(search_url, auth=HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication=OPTIONAL), verify=False)
data = r.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
mask = df['assigneeIdentity'].apply(lambda x: '<your value to filter here>' in x)
df1 = df[mask] # The mask will return values that are True (i.e. - what you want)
```

Comment: I ended up moving to a different API version after all the JSON issues with the one generating the above output.  However, I did test this, and I still had problems with an error about array lengths being different.

Comment: "an error about array lengths being different." Huh, that's weird. Sounds like you would have to create a blank dataframe with the max row count for all columns, then populate it. As a side note, another good filter is `df[df['assigneeIdentity'].str.contains('<your filter value>')`.  Just came across that one this week, too. You might need to convert the data type before using it since it works on string types.