# Selection in dataframe with array as column value

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a dataframe filled with twitter data. The columns are:

- row_id : Int
- content : String
- mentions : [String]
- value : Int

So for every tweet I have it's row id in the dataframe, the content of the tweet, the mentions used in it (for example: '@foo') as an array of strings and a value that I calculated based on the content of the tweet.

An example of a row would be:

- row_id : 12
- content : 'Game of Thrones was awful'
- mentions : ['@hbo', '@tv', '@dissapointment', '@whatever']
- value: -0.71

So what I need is a way to do the following 3 things:

- find all rows that contain the mention '@foo' in the mentions-field
- find all rows that ONLY contain the mention '@foo' in the mentions-field
- above two but checking for an array of strings instead of checking for only one handle

If anyone could help met with this, or even just point me in the right direction that'd be great.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41518920/python-pandas-how-to-query-if-a-list-type-column-contains-something

Comment: @IcedLance Thanks! Totally missed this answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call your DataFrame df.

For the first task you use:

```
result = df[(Dataframe(df['mentions'].tolist()) == '@foo').any(1)]
```

Here, the `Dataframe(df['mentions'])` creates a new DataFrame where each column is a mention and each row a tweet.

Then `== '@foo'` generates a boolean dataframe containing True where the mentions are '@foo'.

Finally `.any(1)` returns a boolean index which elements are True if any element in the row is True.

I think with this help you can manage to solve the rest for yourself.

Comment: This returns to an empty dataframe. I also tried checking what `Dataframe(df['mentions'])` looks like, but it's just a 1-column dataframe with only the one 'mentions' column containing the array of mentions for each tweet. I'd post a screenshot of my output to better explain it, but I don't know how to do that in a comment :v

Comment: Sorry, you should make first df['mentions'].tolist().