# Using the Pandas query function and testing if a string is in a column containing lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame where one column contains lists e.g.:

```
columnA
--------
[val1, val2]
[val1, val3]
...
```

I want to use the `df.query()` syntax to return only rows where a given value exists in the array. But am getting errors, I'm trying things like:

`df.query('"val1" in columnA')`
Or `df.query('val1 in columnA)`

I've also tried splitting the value out into its own variable to see if that helped without success:
`val = "val1"` df.query('@val in columnA')
Neither is running. Has anyone done something similar and got it working?

Comment: Is using the `query()` method a requirement for an answer, or does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41518920/python-pandas-how-to-query-if-a-list-type-column-contains-something) answer for you?

Comment: I would prefer to use `query()` - just for consistency as that's what I'm using in the rest of my code.

Answer (score 1):

I did not use "query" but I think this can help you. You can change the value so I think having a function is a good idea.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'columnA': [[1, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4], [6, 2], [0, 10] ,[2, 8]]})

def check(data, value):
   temp_df = []
   for i in range(len(data)):
      if value in data['columnA'].iloc[i]:
         temp_df.append(data['columnA'].iloc[i])
      else:
         pass
   return temp_df

new_df = check(data = df, value = 3)
```