# How to filter a column of a dataframe based on corresponding values in another column, using a list comprehension?

Tags: python, dataframe, list, list-comprehension

I would like to filter a dataframe and create a list using a list comprehension. My attemps so far were not successful.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A" : [1,2,3],
    "B" : ["a_b_c_some_word", "de_f_some_word", "g_hi_some_word"]
})

lst = [i for i in df["A"] if word in df["B"]]
print(lst)
[]
```

I'm expecting `[1]` as an ouput for this example but keep getting empty list? I was hoping someone can explain what I'm missing here.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to accomplish here is to check if ```word``` exists in any of those strings and return their corresponding numbers from column A... I just realized it's not very clear from my instructions, I apologize

Comment: I don't undersand your list comprehension. The `if` condition has nothing to do with the element of the iteration. So it will always be true and you'll get all `i` values, or it's never true and you get an empty list.

Comment: The `if` condition needs to use `i`.

Comment: Or maybe you want to iterate over `zip(df['A'], df['B'])`?

Comment: I would like to take the masking code that produce the correct values and convert that into a list comprehension

Comment: so in this example ```filtered``` needs to match ```lst```

Comment: What is the need for list comprehension here?

Comment: You _can_ do it by a list comprehension, but it'll be faster to use pandas for any dataframe of significant size

Comment: in  case the columns don't exist, I need it to return empty list

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
lst = [i for i, j in zip(df['A'], df['B']) if word in j]
```

This iterates over the two columns in parallel, returning the value of one column if the condition is true for the corresponding value in the other column.

Comment: This might be a separate question, but I was curious how would you return the row of that dataframe if condition is met. So instead of returning just ```[1]``` it would return that entire row

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41518920/python-pandas-how-to-query-if-a-list-type-column-contains-something