# Dataframe isin() on list of dicts which have list as property value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, isin

i want to get the objects which contain a certain value stored in their property list "value" in this case.

```
import pandas as pd

mydataset = [{"name": "test", "values": ["3", "7", "2"]}, {"name": "test2", "values": ["4", "1", "7"]}]

myvar = pd.DataFrame.from_records(mydataset)

print(myvar[myvar["values"].isin(["3"])])
```

This codes gives an empty dataframe back.

If i initialize the dataframe with single object it works. How can i filter them when the list is a property value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python & Pandas: How to query if a list-type column contains something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41518920/python-pandas-how-to-query-if-a-list-type-column-contains-something)

Comment: Try `print(myvar[myvar["values"].map({'3'}.issubset)])`.

Answer (score 4):

You cona use  `apply()` theis way:

```
import pandas as pd

mydataset = [{"name": "test", "values": ["3", "7", "2"]}, {"name": "test2", "values": ["4", "1", "7"]}]
myvar = pd.DataFrame.from_records(mydataset)

filtered_data = myvar[myvar["values"].apply(lambda x: "3" in x)]
print(filtered_data)
```

which gives

```
   name     values
0  test  [3, 7, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop over the values.

If you have a single target:

```
target = '3'

out = myvar[[any(val == target for val in l) for l in myvar['values']]]
```

Or, if you want to match several values (all of the targets):

```
target = {'3', '7'}

out = myvar[[target.issubset(l) for l in myvar['values']]]
```

any of the targets:

```
target = {'3', '10'}

out = myvar[[bool(target.intersection(l)) for l in myvar['values']]]
```

Output:

```
   name     values
0  test  [3, 7, 2]
```

Comment: Has this any advantage over the solution above?

Comment: @JoB it should be faster, `apply` is a wrapper around a python loop and thus has extra overhead.

Comment: Note that you can also write `myvar[[target in l for l in myvar['values']]]` for the first case.